# Laravel REST API route Problem in Resource file

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8, rest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
        

            'href' => [
                'self' => route('reviews.index', $this->id),
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

My Route Is Coming  `"href":{"self":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/api\/products\/1\/reviews"}` like this,
How am I gonna solve it? thank you

Answer (score 1):

**It's happening because of json response. json alway encode the code, so You can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` to skip url slashes**

```
response()->json(..., 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

> In laravel [eloquent api resource](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources) also have the same problem.The best
> way to apply json options to your Response or ResponseCollection is:

```
public function withResponse($request, $response)
{
    $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
```